# Qt: Display Filesystem in A Customized Way inside QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, filesystems

I am working on Qt app where I need to display Filesystem inside a `Qtreeview`. Basically my idea is to customize the filesystem in such a way that Removable Drives come under one section and Local Drives come under another. I tried to achieve it using `QFSFileEngine` but I have been successful to some extent. here is the code:

```
pSystemSecondaryModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
pSystemSecondaryModel->setRootPath(QDir::currentPath());

list = QFSFileEngine::drives();
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    qDebug() << list.at(i).absoluteDir();
}

m_model = new QStandardItemModel(0,0);

QList<QStandardItem *> LocalItem;
LocalItem.insert(0,new QStandardItem("Local Drives"));
LocalItem.at(0)->setEditable(false);
m_model->insertRow(0,LocalItem);

QList<QStandardItem *> RemovableItem;
RemovableItem.insert(0,new QStandardItem("Removable Drives"));
RemovableItem.at(0)->setEditable(false);
m_model->insertRow(1,RemovableItem);

for (int i = 0; i < list.count(); i++)
{
    QString str = list.at(i).absolutePath();
    Localchild = new QStandardItem(str);
    QStandardItem* LocalparentItem = m_model->item(0,0);
    Localchild->setEditable(false);
    LocalparentItem->appendRow(Localchild);
}

QStandardItem* Removablechild = new QStandardItem();
QStandardItem* RemovableparentItem = m_model->item(1,0);
Removablechild->setEditable(false);
RemovableparentItem->appendRow(Removablechild);
ui->PrimTreeView->setModel(m_model);
```

When I run the app, it shows Local Drives and Removable Drives root node. Under Local Drive node, I find all C: D: E: etc as children whereas Removable Drive seems to be empty i.e. without any children.
Here is the scenario which is the current output:

```
- Local Drives
   C:/
   D:/
   E:/

- Removable Drives
```

But when I click on each drive, I am not able to see the subdirectories at all. Ideally when I click C:/ i should be able to see `Windows`, `Program Files` folder etc. Its totally empty. How can I achieve it? Please help

Comment: You are not even using your `pSystemSecondaryModel`, so really all you have is a `QStandardItemModel` with the drive entries you added manually.

Comment: @jdi:yes you are right but if I set the `pSystemSecondaryModel` as `setModel()` then it displays all the drives in each row which is something I dont want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably know, you are not using your `QFileSystemModel` at all, and simply populating a `QStandardItemModel` with manual entries that you look up.

If your goal is to present custom groupings of file system listing, what you might try and do is use multiple  `QFileSystemModel` instances, with roots set to each of your drives. So you would continue to set up the top level drives as you are doing, but for each of those drives you might need a model set to that root. And then create a map between those items and their private models.

Then you would have to re-implement probably index, hasChildren, rowCount, columnCount, and maybe some other read-only methods, to check into the models of those drives. So if for instance the model needs to know if `C:/` has children, your `hasChildren()` would have to look up the mapping of that index to the hidden `C:/` root model, and do a child count on that model.

Another way is to just subclass `QStandardItemModel` (or `QAbstractItemModel`) and do the file system listings yourself instead of using `QFileSystemModel`. This would allow you to just set your fixed root items, being the categories, and drive letters, and then check the listings as they are expanded or collapsed. Again this will require subclassing a model which is not always a great beginners Qt experience.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I really appreciate it :) Sadly I am new into this Qt world. I am still not sure how to go ahead with it. Can you please help me out? a sample code or something would really be helpful

Comment: I was trying to avoid sample code because it's a bit involved :-) If you are ok with seeing an example in python, I am much faster at pyqt and would be willing to show a small rough bit of code.

Comment: Alright I will get some idea if you can explain it using python :) please

Comment: Unfortunately its non-trivial to give an example :-/ It requires some custom model functionality.

Comment: :Well this surely looks difficult for me. I was actually thinking of the second approach which is basically to subclass QStandardItemModel but then again I am clueless about it :(

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I misunderstood your question, but I think you are looking for something similar to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92biLZST6Vg&list=SP2D1942A4688E9D63&index=49)